# Submit form data with ajax without refresh

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

I have a page with multiple forms, which delete rows in a MySQL database. The forms are also populated from the MySQL database.

I'm trying to sumbit the forms without refreshing the pages, but the rows are not getting removed from my database.

**Update**:
I didn't originally mention that the div which contains the forms i dynamically generated.

The form is based on a option from a select list. Code:

```
      <form>
        <h3>Vælg medlem</h3>
            <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
            <?php
            $i = 0;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
              { if (!$i++) echo "<option selected='selected'>Vælg medlem</option>" ?>

                <option value="<?php echo $row[medlemmer_id]; ?>"><?php echo $row[medlemmer_navn]; ?></option>

                <?php } $i++; ?>
            </select>
        </form>
```

The form uses JS to add the forms to a div on the page. Code:

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
};
</script>
```

**End of update**

The form:

```
  <form id="myform2">
    <p><?php echo $row[boder_navn]; ?> <?php echo $row[boder_pris]; ?> kr. - <?php echo $dato; ?></p>
    <input type="hidden" id="relation_id" name="relation_id" value="<? echo $row[relation_id]; ?>"/>
    <input name="submit" type="submit"/>
 </form>
```

The script to send data:

```
  $(function () {

    $('#myform2').on('submit', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'delete.php',
        data: $("#relation_id").val();,
        success: function () {
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
      });

    });

  });
```

The php file for deleting rows:

```
 <?php
 mysql_connect("#######", "########", "#######") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("#######") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_query("DELETE FROM boder_has_medlemmer WHERE relation_id = ". $_POST['relation_id'] .""); 
 ?>
```

If i just use a form with `method="POST"` and `action="delete.php` it's working. Meaning that the row in question is deleted, but the page refreshes.

Any suggestions to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Any error you are getting in console ?

Comment: if the console doesn't show anything - take a look at the php error log. add an error output to your delete.php, just to see if the ajax call really fires the php. maybe it's a simple path issue...

Comment: The console is not showing any errors. How would i apply an error log to the php script?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
data: $("#relation_id").val();,
```

to

```
data: {relation_id: $("#relation_id").val()},
```

or after e.preventDefault(); add this line

```
var rel_id = $("#relation_id").val();
```

and

```
data: {relation_id: rel_id},
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything - but you made me aware of a curly bracket mistake.

Comment: Nope no errors - and I'm not sure how to check if the Ajax request actually is made.

Comment: For you the easiest way to log what happened should be adding this line in delete.php
mysql_query("INSERT INTO some_table_name (an_column_name) VALUES ('.mysql_real_escape_string(print_r($_POST, true)).')");
you have to create an table with an column and replace their names in prev code, this should save any post request to your table and you can check it
or adding this after success function in js: error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){console.log(textStatus);}

Comment: What do you mean by "replacing their names in prev code"? I have created a table and column, and tried running it again, but nothing is added to the tabler. `mysql_query("INSERT INTO error_check(e1) VALUES ('.mysql_real_escape_string(print_r($_POST, true)).')");`

Comment: I guess there is an ajax error, add this after success function in js: `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){console.log(jqXHR); console.log(textStatus); console.log(errorThrown);}` this will be triggered when ajax error happens and will write to your console whats wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61112/discussion-between-axel-and-karsten-tietje).

Answer (score 1):

place

```
return false;
```

after the ajax call function and change how you place the argument

```
$(function () {

$('#myform2').on('submit', function (e) {

   e.preventDefault();

   var rel_id = $("#relation_id").val();

   $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'delete.php',
      data: {
         relation_id: rel_id
      },
      success: function () {
        alert('form was submitted');
      }
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```